# How to determine Mac OS X version in shell script?

Tags: macos, shell, version

I need to run make with one parameters set if it is running under Capitan and with other parameters in Sierra.
In other words:
I run in command line:

> sw_version
>   ProductName: Mac OS X
>   ProductVersion: 10.13.6

How I can get the value of ProductVersion to the variable and check it
if current  OS version <10.13 then
else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the `sw_vers` command. See examples here :
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mac-osx-find-tell-operating-system-version-from-bash-prompt/

to get product version :

```
sw_vers | grep ProductVersion | cut -d':' -f2
```

to compare the parsed value :

```
base_ver=10.13
ver=$(sw_vers | grep ProductVersion | cut -d':' -f2 | tr -d ' ')
if [ $(echo -e $base_ver"\n"$ver | sort -V | tail -1) == "$base_ver" ]
then 
   echo "older"
else 
   echo "newer"
fi
```

Comment: Thanx! how to read the value 10.13 to a variable in script and then compare?

Comment: Thanx! One note: tere is the flag: sw_vers -productVersion and probably we do not need grep

Comment: Btw, ver=10.13.6 and thats why it compares incorrectly. How to get only 10.13 from ver? or separately 10 and 13 and then compare

Comment: what you mean it compares incorrectly ? if ver=10.13.6 then it is newer than 10.13, which is what my suggestion will output. In any case if you only want to get 10.13 for $ver, you can try : `ver=$(sw_vers | grep ProductVersion | cut -d':' -f2 | tr -d ' ' | rev| cut -d'.' -f2-| rev)`

Comment: `sw_vers -productVersion` gives the same output as `sw_vers | grep ProductVersion | cut -d':' -f2`, just a bit of a cleaner way of getting it

Comment: it should not be accepted answer as it always prints "newer".

Answer (score 1):

The below command works on latest versions of macOS:

```
os_ver=${$(sw_vers -productVersion)}
if [[ $os_ver -gt 10.13 ]]; then
    echo "$os_ver  is above 10.13"
else
    echo "$os_ver is below 10.13"
fi
```